# GetElementyID("ID").innerHTML = value doesn´t work as expected

Tags: html, css, onclicklistener

**I try to change the textvalue and the color of strings in the HTML in a top navigation bar (img ressource deleted).**

What is the mistake here? Is it enough to reference the ID of an ELement if it is nested in a class? Currently this approach does not work (no change in HTML).

Would have been a quick test to replace the text values on the HTML page with custom / translated texts via the navigation bar (choice of language).

**Description of malfunction:**
Textelements don´t change, when the button element is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head></head>
<style>

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 645px;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  position: center;
  margin-left: -32px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div a img {
    width: 21px;
    height: 12px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

</style>
<body>
    
<script>

    function funcAT(){
        document.getElementById("TEST1").innerHTML ="TestOfFunction";
        document.getElementById("TEST1").style.color = "red";
    }
    
    function funcDE(){
        document.getElementById("TEST2").innerHTML ="TestOfFunction 2";
        document.getElementById("TEST2").style.color = "red";
    }
    
        
</script>

<div class="topnav">
    
  <a class="lang_btn"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i>&nbsp; Verfügbare Sprachen und Länder</a>
        <a><img id="AT" onclick="funcAT()" src="...">&nbsp;&nbsp;AT</a>
        <a><img id="DE" onclick="funcDE()"  src="...">&nbsp;&nbsp;DE</a>
        <a><img id="PL" onclick="funcPL()"  src="...">&nbsp;&nbsp;PL</a>
        <a><img id="RO" onclick="funcRO()"  src="...">&nbsp;&nbsp;RO</a>
        <a><img id="UK" onclick="funcUK()"  src="...">&nbsp;&nbsp;UK</a>
</div><br>

<p id="TEST" >predefined value</p>
<p id="TEST1">predefined value 1</p>
<p id="TEST2">predefined value 2</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens instead? Are you sure this problem is related to CSS?

Comment: This is a sharepoint Websitesite with implemented CSS/HTML by modern script editor.

Comment: it's not clear to me what you mean when you ask what's wrong. If you click on those pictures having the onclick handler it will perform the desired action. But those images here have a fake src so they won't load. Maybe are you not clicking those exact elements? try to set a `img{border: solid 1px color;}` to highlight where those elements actually are and click those

Comment: It [works for me](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/abPjreM). I did have to add the function calls: `funcAT();` and `funcDE();`. did you forget those?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the function calls are embedded in the `onclick` attribute of the trigger pictures eg.: `onclick="funcAT()"`

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I deleted the image src because it refers to a local path.

It doesn't work in the sense that the sample values in the text fields (p-tags) are not changed after the img is clicked. (They aren´t red and the content of it doesn´t change)

Comment: according to that exact snippet, it actually works as intended. Maybe are you using a different html in your test? do you have maybe duplicate ids?

Comment: When you created your reduced test case, did you remove some href atteibutes from the an elements? If so, you removed the cause of the problem.

Comment: No, i just deleted the src of the img (because .png, which is saved in sharepoint, so the link wouldn´t load the image), all other components of the HTML are the same.

@Diego D
Unfortunately, the p tags do not change in appearance / content for me.

Comment: OK, I missed that, but [it still works](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/abPjreM?editors=1111) for me (now pressing the AT and DE links).

Comment: Thank you all so far!

Okay, unfortunately I can't understand why it doesn't work for me either. The only thing I can think of is that the execution of JS / scripts is blocked (Edge).

Will try to raise if it is an internal IT problem / sharepoint problem and try if the onclick functions work for button elements.

Comment: Have you checked for error messages in [the browser console](https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/)? Any Javascript error can stop execution of almost all Javascript.

Comment: Please keep in mind that all clarification should be part of your initial post. Please edit it to contain all details

Comment: Okay, I get it now!

It only works if you click DIRECTLY on the picture.
At the moment it looks like a button (with image+adjacent text), but the complete element is not responsible! E.g. clicking on the text or the background of the element naturally doesn´t change nothing.

Unfortunately I didn't notice this because the img is very small.

Comment: To add to what Nico Haase said: Any solution to your problem should be posted in an answer to the question, not in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Resolution:**
 Using button instead of img+text for top navigation bar element, due to with actual approach the effect only occurs if clicking directly on the img element.

Unfortunately, I didn't notice that because I interpreted the entire element as a button in terms of functionality (but didn't implement it that way, but as separate a and img elements -> so only the images responds to clicks).

So there was no wrong behaviour, but a non-correct implementation.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What could also help is to attach the onclick handler to the `<a>` element, instead of to the `<img>` element.

Answer (score -1):

you set onclick on `<img>` tag, so you have to click on `<img>` to replace and change the color of the text inside of the `<p>` tag.
I think you want to create a button, for this purpose, you need to move onlick from `<img>` to `<a>` tag.

```
<a onclick="funcAT()"><img id="AT" src="...">&nbsp;&nbsp;AT</a>
```